# How to get AngularJS to update the DOM on ng-repeat array splice? $scope.$apply() returns an error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, angularjs-ng-repeat

**SOLVED** - I have this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/vzChlEgJ8Cj8BwWMlF7f?p=preview) which demonstrates the issues I am facing.  This is simple image uploader that also uses `FileReader` to display the image (thanks to [angular-file-uploads](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload)). I have placed this in a dynamic form that which can be added and removed.

Issues:

1. In this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/vzChlEgJ8Cj8BwWMlF7f?p=preview), the `dataUrl` is not displayed until after `Add
   Another Image` is clicked.  This may be a plunkr only issue since
   the image is displayed nicely in my site.  --SOLVED
2. If you upload an image onto the first form, then click `Add Another Image`, and then click the first tab, then delete the first tab, the data is deleted in `$scope.images` but the DOM is not updated.  Adding a `$scope.$apply()` results in a digest already in progress error.
3. The old file name is displayed in the upload input but the input is actually empty.

My question is: How can the DOM be updated when an image is removed?

**Update:**  Issue #1 is solved, but issues #2 and #3 remain.

**Update2:** I've tried attaching a `$scope.$apply` for the `<input type="file" onchange="..."` but removing the image with `splice()` does not fire an `onchange` event.

**Update3:** I've added a simple text input with a `ng-model="image.caption"` to see if the the DOM would update appropiately. It does.  The DOM also updates properly if `images[0]` is deleted by `images[1]` already has an image.

**Update4:**  Grundy has identified the problem: `track by $index`. Removing that makes everything work as expected.  Not exactly sure why though.

Comment: why you use `track by $index` in your ng-repeat?

Comment: I use `track by $index` so that `angular-file-uploads="{{ $index }}"` know's which image number was uploaded.  I tried removing `track by $index` and it seems to....... work........ Also, it seems that $index works regardless.  I think that solves it!

Comment: @Grundy, I would love for you to add your explanation as an answer.

Comment: `$index` is special variable in _ngRepeat_ it always available and nod depends on how you tracking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You problem with *track by* expression in your *ngRepeat*
As says in doc for [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

> ngRepeat makes the corresponding changes to the DOM:
>
> - When an item is added, a new instance of the template is added to the DOM.
> - When an item is removed, its template instance is removed from the DOM.
> - When items are reordered, their respective templates are reordered in the DOM.

So, in your case when you splice first element, *index* for last element change to *first* and angular think that need just remove last element from DOM, and not need change first.

Also, *$index*, *$last* and etc is a special properties in *ngRepeat* scope, so it avalilable always and not depend on *track by* expresion

Answer (score 1):

Since your directive handles an event that is outside of the digest-cycle in AngularJs, you need to wrap any updates to the scope in `scope.$apply()`.  So in your directive:

```
 reader.onload = function() {
   var dataURL = reader.result;
   scope.$apply(function() {
     scope.$parent.upload(file, dataURL, attributes.angularFileUploads);
   });
 };
```

Comment: instead of `$scope.$apply`, try injecting `$timeout` and do `$timeout(function () { /* stuff with $scope */ });`

Comment: @StickyCube, I did try that before, but it didn't changed anything.  I added a `$timeout` for `$timeout(function() {$scope.images.splice($scope.images.indexOf($scope.image), 1);}, 100);`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that image.dataUrl is cached or something.

adding

`ng-if="image.dataUrl"`

to the `<img>` tag

seems to remedy the situation, however it doesn't solve the underlying issue.. whatever it is.

Comment: The issue as Grundy has hinted at was the `track by $index`.  Removing that makes it work as expected.